# How to download attachments in outlook add-ins?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Is it possible to download attachments in outlook add-ins? I mean trigger 'save as' button by javascript. now I can get attachments by using item.attachments and then get base64 with

```
item.getAttachmentContentAsync
```

by this way i can download manually. But is it possible to make something like 'save as' calling?

I need something like item.attachments[0].saveAs('directory')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Office JavaScript API (`OfficeJS`) doesn't provide anything for triggering built-in commands or saving attachments as a user to the disk. See [Get attachments of an Outlook item from the server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/get-attachments-of-an-outlook-item) for more information.

You can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team go through the planning process.